# Error during installation of Drupal 7 on Linux/Webhosting site

Tags: php, linux, drupal-7, php-extension

I am doing manual installation of Drupal 7 on Linux based web hosting site where CPanel is useless. I am using FTP to do most of the things.

After uploading files via FTP, I have got through 2 steps of Drupal install wizard (Choose profile - Standard, Choose language - English) stuck at **Verify requirements** - PHP extensions - Disabled, see:

[image: Error screenshot]

Stuck with **PHP extensions - Disabled**, any advice on how to fix it?

Update: I previously had an error with phpinfo, but have now resolved that.

Comment: Thanks halfer. I do not know what to try in the first place. I need detailed steps to make installation successful.

Comment: You have not given us any information about how things are configured on your system, so as it stands it is unlikely we can help. You mention cPanel, but say it is useless - do you have cPanel or not? In general your host will offer a web panel to configure PHP, or a configurable php.ini file.

Comment: After your edits, we still don't know if you have cPanel or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have shell access: stop and get a better host. Chose one that will give you shell access, or provides Drupal hosting as a service (like Pantheon or Platform.sh which provide you appropriate alternatives). Even when you get can get Drupal running in an environment with cPanel and FTP access only, it will be a struggle at all times.

If you do have shell access, then you need to make sure all the required elements are installed.  Drupal will flag those for you at the requirements step.

This host is also running a very old version of PHP, which you do not want to be using since no supported version of Drupal requires 5.3 anymore (Drupal 7 and 8 will both run on 5.5, 5.6, and I think 7).

Comment: Thanks acrosman! I have worked with webhosting service and enabled phpInfo, now I am stuck with error "PHP extensions-Disabled". I would need some pointer on how to get this surpassed. I saw some posts that use/modify php.ini that I did not able to find on Drupal 7 setup folders.

Comment: My primary recommendation is still to change hosts. That said, php.ini is not part of Drupal it's part of the server setup. Depending on your host they may give you access to it or may not. You also need them to install gb (and a supported version of PHP).

Comment: After lots of back and forth, finally hosts able to install php-gd library - all good.